# C Why when passing this int by value, it is incorrectly passing 0 every time

Tags: c, arrays, struct, pass-by-reference

Ok so sorry for the length of the code block, but I am at a loss. The variable currentProcess holds the index of the last structue added to the array. I have included print statements to prove that the value of currentProcess is being incremented correctly as elements are being added. However, when I then pass this variable to the function printCurrent() it passes the value 0. I included the whole program as it stands, because I have no idea where this error could be coming from, any help is appreciated. thanks in advance. (Apologies for the blank switch case block, this is a work in progress)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 10

typedef  struct {
    int pCount;
    float pAccul;
    int pAddress;
}pState;
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char status[10];
    pState state;
    char priority;
}PCB;

//function prototypes
int addProcess(PCB*, PCB, int*);
PCB getPcb(PCB);
void printCurrent(PCB[], int);


int main()
{
    PCB process;
    PCB pArray[SIZE];
    PCB* pcbPtr;
    char option = ' ';
    int i;
    int currentProcess;
    int* cpPtr;

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        pArray[i].id = 0;
    }//end for

    cpPtr = &currentProcess;
    pcbPtr = pArray;

    //simple menu with 4 options
    while(option != '0')
    {
        printf("\n-----Menu-----\n");
        printf("\n1)   Add Process\n");
        printf("\n2)   Delete Process\n");
        printf("\n3)   Display PCB\n");
        printf("\n0)   Quit\n");
        scanf("%1s", &option);

        switch(option)
        {
        case '1': 
              addProcess(pcbPtr, process, cpPtr);
              printf("\nCHECK CHECK %d CHECK CHECK\n",  currentProcess);//ERROR CHECK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
              break;

        case '2':
              //deleteProcess();
              break;

        case '3':
              printCurrent(pArray, currentProcess);
              break;

        case '0':
            exit(0);
        default:
              printf("Error! Choose From Available Options!!");
              break;

        }//end main switch/case
    }//end main while
}//end main


int addProcess(PCB* ptr, PCB newSt, int* currentProcess)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        if((ptr+i)->id == 0)
        {
            ptr[i] = getPcb(newSt);
            *currentProcess = i;
            printf("%d", *currentProcess);//ERROR CHECK!!!
            return 0;
        }//end if
    }//end for
    return 1;
}//end addProcess()


PCB getPcb(PCB new)
{
    printf("\nEnter Id\n");
    scanf("%d", &new.id);
    printf("\nEnter Status\n");
    scanf("%s", new.status);
    printf("\nEnter Process Counter Value\n");
    scanf("%d", &new.state.pCount);
    printf("\nEnter Acculumator Value\n");
    scanf("%f", &new.state.pAccul);
    printf("\nEnter Process Address (Unsigned Int)\n");
    scanf("%d", &new.state.pAddress);
    printf("\nEnter Priority (l/h)\n");
    scanf("%1s", &new.priority);

    return new;
}//end getPcb()


void printCurrent(PCB array[], int currentProcess)
{
    printf("!!!!!!!!%d!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", currentProcess);//!!!!!!!!!!
    printf("\n---------------------------\n");
    printf("\nProcess ID: %d\n", array[currentProcess].id);
    printf("Status: %s\n", array[currentProcess].status);
    printf("Process Counter: %d\n", array[currentProcess].state.pCount);
    printf("Acculumator Value: %.2f\n",    array[currentProcess].state.pAccul);
    printf("Process Address: %d\n",    array[currentProcess].state.pAddress);
    printf("Priority: %c\n", array[currentProcess].priority);
    printf("\n----------------------------\n");

}//end printCurrent()
```

Comment: Please show a log of your test run. Include all input and output.

Comment: What's the point of passing a parameter to `getPcb`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Fair point but could that really be an issue?

Comment: @0_insomniac_0 no it's not an issue

Comment: Not directly an isue, but the variables `cpPtr` and `pcbPtr` are useless and nly adding confusion, use `&currentProcess` and `pArray` directly.

Comment: `scanf("%1s", &option);` is a buffer overflow, causing undefined behaviour. The buffer size must be at least 1 more than the count for `%s` .  `" %c"` would probably be a better format string.

Comment: passing `process` as parameter causes undefined behaviour because it's an uninitialized variable. To fix this, remove that parameter since it is not used anyway

Comment: `scanf("%1s", &new.priority);` has the same bug

Comment: `scanf("%s", new.status)` should be `"%9s"`

Comment: @M.M I was using "%c" but for some reason the getPcb() function was skipping the step in the function. I also tried get getChar() but got the same result. %1s is working for now if only 1 char given as input. I just realised I have named the structure "new" when declaring getPcb(). Im wondering if this is overwriting anything..

Comment: @0_insomniac_0 `" %c"`, not `"%c"`.  You should fix bugs, not say "it's working for now". Because it's not working otherwise you would not have posted this question. `%1s` is a bug.

Comment: @M.M I appreciate that. I will sort out those issues. The problem was in fact line 99: `PCB getPcb(PCB new)` I hadn't realised `new` was a kewword in C. The bug is now fixed. Thanks for all your help and advice

Comment: `new` is not a keyword in C.

Comment: ? I just saw that now, I assumed it was as it became highlighted in the question code. When I changed the variable name it  worked... I am lost, I will fix the '%1s' as advised

Comment: I think this site uses common highlighting for C and C++ .  If that's the only change you made then it's a good sign that there is still undefined behaviour in your program somewhere.  (You should remove that parameter entirely , since it is causing undefined behaviour by passing it in the first place)

Comment: Good advise, will do, thanks again

Answer (score -1):

M.M is right. `{scanf("%1s", &option);}` is ugly. Make if "%c".

Here is changed code:

```
//function prototypes
int addProcess(PCB* arr, int*); //you don't need newSt
PCB getPcb();                  
void printCurrent(PCB[], int);
```

---

```
case '1':
        // address of first element of the array is passed
        // this way, you are letting addProcess know the location
        // of pArray on main()'s stack so that it can fill it
        addProcess(&pArray, &currentProcess);
        break;
```

---

```
int addProcess(PCB* ptr, int* currentProcess)
{
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
                if(ptr[i].id == 0)
                {
                        ptr[i] = getPcb();
                       // getPcb() will initialize and return 
                       // a new PCB which is assigned to the                      
                       // appropriate location of array
                        *currentProcess = i;
                        printf("%d", *currentProcess);//ERROR CHECK!!!
                        return 0;
                        // the function is anyway returning an int 
                        // why not return "i"?
                }//end if
        }//end for
        return 1;
}//end addProcess()
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I have made those changes. The function returns an int in place of a boolean. Since i can have a value between 0 and 10 I do not use it

Comment: That's not a matter of style, but the difference between correct and wrong code.

Comment: By "ugly" I did not mean the style or aesthetics of the code; I meant it is an ugly coding practice that can lead to serious consequences.